# Content of List gets Lost between start() and update()

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, indexing

i try to create a list with tiles from tilemap and use that list to get coords of tiles on the tilemap.
I guess by looking at the comments in the update func the problem is pretty obvious but i dont know what to do

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject[] getCount;
    private int count;
    public int maxBags = 1;
    public Transform goldBag;
    public List<int> possibleTiles;
    public int possibleTilesLength;
    private int randomTileNr;
    public List<int> copyOfPossibleTiles;

    void Start()
    {
        Tilemap tilemap = GetComponent<Tilemap>();
        BoundsInt bounds = tilemap.cellBounds;
        TileBase[] allTiles = tilemap.GetTilesBlock(bounds);
        List<int> possibleTiles = new List<int>();
        for (int x = 0; x < bounds.size.x; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < bounds.size.y; y++) {
                TileBase tile = allTiles[x + y * bounds.size.x];
                if (tile != null) {
                    possibleTiles.Add(x);
                    Debug.Log(possibleTiles.Count);
                    possibleTiles.Add(y);
                    Debug.Log(possibleTiles.Count);
                    possibleTilesLength = possibleTiles.Count;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {
        getCount = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("bagCoins");
        if(getCount.Length < maxBags)
        {
            randomTileNr = (int)UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,possibleTilesLength/2)*2;
            Debug.Log(possibleTiles.Count);                 //prints 0
            Debug.Log(possibleTilesLength);                 //prints 128
            Debug.Log(randomTileNr);                        //prints random even number between 0 and 128
            Debug.Log(copyOfPossibleTiles[randomTileNr]);   //prints error index out of range.
            maxBags = 0;
Instantiate(goldBag, new Vector3(possibleTiles[randomTileNr],possibleTiles[randomTileNr+1],0), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome to the subject of variable scope

Answer (score 4):

You are storing them in a **local variable** in `Start`

```
List<int> possibleTiles = new List<int>();
for (int x = 0; x < bounds.size.x; x++) {
...
```

which hides the field with the same name. So your changes made in `Start` do not change the globally known list `possibleTiles` your `Update` method tries to access.

Rather use your field you already have and initialize it correctly

```
public List<int> possibleTiles = new List<int>();
```

and in `Start` do only

```
possibleTiles.Clear();
for (int x = 0; x < bounds.size.x; x++) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this is probably what you want

```
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject[] getCount;
    private int count;
    public int maxBags = 1;
    public Transform goldBag;
    public List<int> possibleTiles = new List<int>(); // Initialized list holding possible tiles
    public int possibleTilesLength;
    private int randomTileNr;
    public List<int> copyOfPossibleTiles;

    void Start()
    {
        Tilemap tilemap = GetComponent<Tilemap>();
        BoundsInt bounds = tilemap.cellBounds;
        TileBase[] allTiles = tilemap.GetTilesBlock(bounds);
        // Remove the line below since we want to declare the list as member variable and we already initialized it
        //List<int> possibleTiles = new List<int>();
        
        possibleTiles.Clear();
        for (int x = 0; x < bounds.size.x; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < bounds.size.y; y++) {
                TileBase tile = allTiles[x + y * bounds.size.x];
                if (tile != null) {
                    possibleTiles.Add(x);
                    Debug.Log(possibleTiles.Count);
                    possibleTiles.Add(y);
                    Debug.Log(possibleTiles.Count);
                    possibleTilesLength = possibleTiles.Count;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {
        getCount = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("bagCoins");
        if(getCount.Length < maxBags)
        {
            randomTileNr = (int)UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,possibleTilesLength/2)*2;
            Debug.Log(possibleTiles.Count);                 //prints 0
            Debug.Log(possibleTilesLength);                 //prints 128
            Debug.Log(randomTileNr);                        //prints random even number between 0 and 128
            Debug.Log(copyOfPossibleTiles[randomTileNr]);   //prints error index out of range.
            maxBags = 0;
Instantiate(goldBag, new Vector3(possibleTiles[randomTileNr],possibleTiles[randomTileNr+1],0), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```